# ¿Como saber si un JTable se encuentra vació?

Tags: javascript, java

Como verificar si un JTable se encuentra vació, tengo algo de este estilo.

```
if (jTable1.getRowCount() == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Existen Datos", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Si hay Datos a Exportar", "Información", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Las validaciones que mencionas no resuelven tu problema?
Te marca algun error?

Comment: No, solo se va por el else, cuando la JTable se encuentra vacía. @pachecoton

Comment: Agregale tambien esto: jTable1.getSelectedRow()!=-1 a tu validacion.

Comment: Lo solucione con esta condición  **int Seleccionada = jTable1.getSelectedRowCount();
        if (Seleccionada != 0) {
          ;
        }**

Comment: Igual Muchas Gracias @pachecoton